# First brew question

Tags: first-time-brewer

I've moved the brew into a casket after the initial 4 days after seeing that the overall yeast had nearly stopped working. The cask is pressurized as expected from the CO2 (now @10 days). However I think I let the cask to cool down over a period of 4 days when I went off for a few days, so the FG is only just above the red on my hydrometer.
Would putting the cask back into a warmer spot, start fermentation off again, with the residual yeast left in the beer? The reading before fermentation was 1.030 and is now showing 1.010, or just 2 notches above the red band, which If I'm right works out as a .020 difference making the alcohol level at 2.6%.?

If I see little to no change, can I restart the fermentation, or like said in an earlier thread, just sup it as a low alc brew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible that the yeast stalled due to temp.  Since you didn't tell us the temp,  its hard to advise.  I'd suggest keeping the temp at close to 70F.  check again after a couple days.  You may see a further drop.  But at this point it will be slower, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

Those gravities are close to only a few styles Scottish 60, Scottish Light Ale. For example

1.010 FG is good any lower and it will be dry or watery.

- What is the beer style and ingedients?
- 4 days primary is pretty short. While it's normal for yeast to stop showing noticeable signs of fermentation in that time it usually does need a few more days to clean up.

As it is now I would say taste it, it's probably as good as it's going to get as far as fermentation goes.

Answer (score 0):

I re-read the instructions on the back of another sheet I'd overlooked. I had forgotten to add the 2.5oz of sugar to the cask to kick off the secondary fermentation. Doh! So I just added it and will see if the yeasties are still on the go :-) FYI I originally had the mixing barrel temp at 22oC or 72F. It's now back in my airing cubbard and I have it back at 70F. Smells great. It's a Woodfordes Norfolk Wherry Ale. I hope it tastes as good as it smells, after the fermentation is sone

Answer (score 0):

Warming it up may restart the ferment.  You may want to consider off gassing the cask a bit too.  The pressure build up will slow the yeast.  If you are going to add that priming sugar then you'll have to off gas at that time anyway.